# Azure machine learning unable to load pytorch Model from the outputs folder

Tags: python, azure, pytorch, computer-vision

I am unable to load saved pytorch model from the outputs folder in my other scripts.
I am using following lines of code to save the model:

```
    os.makedirs("./outputs/model", exist_ok=True)
    
    torch.save({
        'model_state_dict': copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict()),
        'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict()
        }, './outputs/model/best-model.pth')
    
    new_run.upload_file("outputs/model/best-model.pth", "outputs/model/best-model.pth")
    saved_model = new_run.register_model(model_name='pytorch-model', model_path='outputs/model/best-model.pth')
```

and using the following code to access it:

```
global model
best_model_path = 'outputs/model/best-model.pth'
model_checkpoint = torch.load(best_model_path)
model.load_state_dict(model_checkpoint['model_state_dict'], strict = False)
```

but when I run the above mentioned code, I get this error: No such file or directory: './outputs/model/best-model.pth'

Also I want to know is there a way to get the saved model from Azure Models? I have tried to get it by using following lines of code:

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
model = Model(ws, "Pytorch-model")
```

but it returns Model type object which returns error on model.eval() (error: Model has no such attribute eval()).

Answer (score 0):

There is no global output folder. If you want to use a Model in a new script you need to give the script the model as an input or register the model and download the model from the new script.

The Model object form `from azureml.core.model import Model` is not your pytorch Model. [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py)

You can use `model.register(...)` to register your model. And `model.download(...)` to download you model. Than you can use pytorch to load you model. [2](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)

Comment: Ok thank you very much Kees. One more thing, is there a way to convert the Azure Model to pytorch Model after getting it from this command: model = Model(ws, "Pytorch-model")?

Comment: No it is not your pytorch model. You need to download it. `Model(ws, "Pytorch-model").download(path)` and then load it via `torch.load(path)`. There is a recommended may to load your pytorch model -> https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html. The azure "Model" is just a class to manage your models in azure. ->  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py